# Andr 8.1 fones (LG Stylo 4) and HP 17" LT Win 11 Insider Release. Can I use the laptop as a bridge/router/trunk to push i-net wifi thru enet cables?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, ethernet, bluetooth

So. At my house we have a 5G T-Mobile box that pulls inet out off the sky and I do have a few TVs and a google nest pair on mostly sequested intranets. I already have an enet cable running direct from the T-Mobile box into my Laptop which is sometimes upstairs in the same general area. Half of the google nest pair is plugged into the other enet port.

So when I go downstairs to jam, I don't wanna hafta run an enet cable out the window and back in (I rent). My idea is to minimize all the WiFi noise and lags. So I was thinking just get the laptop down there, find a good WiFi channel and bandwidth amd placement, and tether both fones up, one with USB and the other with enet. I need a USB port or two for my music gear.